# Removing an item from a grouped LLS without re-assigning itemsource?

Tags: windows-phone-8, observablecollection, longlistselector

I currently implemet a LLS (LongListSelector) in a WP8 app that's grouped. I have on it, a context menu from the WPToolkit. I was hoping to find how to remove items from my LLS without re-assigning the LLS's itemssourse. The rational being I want to maintain the position in the list after I remove an item.

What I have now is a main list that keeps all my objects and that's passed to a "GetGroup" function to return an Observable collection of Groups as an item source. I understand now, that simply removing from the main list does not remove from the item source. So instead, I removed from the main list and also cast the ItemSource to an Observable collection and deleted from it. It worked, up until specific instances (removing the second to last item in a list). Then I get  a cryptic exception (value out of bounds). However via debugging all the right values are called and removed, and the exception follows after. How can I do this the correct way? What am I doing incorrectly? My code snippets are below.

Grouping:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Model.Cartitem> cartList = new ObservableCollection<Model.allItems>(); // Overall Item list for current instance.  

    class Group<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Group(string name, IEnumerable<T> items)
            : base(items)
        { 
            this.imagePath = new Uri(name, UriKind.Relative);
        }
        private String _Title;
        private Uri _imagePath;

        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return _Title;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_Title != value)
                {
                    _Title = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
                }
            }
        }


        public Uri imagePath
        {
            get
            {
                return _imagePath;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_imagePath != value)
                {
                    _imagePath = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("imagePath");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    // Functions to Handle Group Lists
    private ObservableCollection<ITemClass> GetItemList()
    {
        return allItems;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Group<ItemClass>> GetItemGroups()
    {
        IEnumerable<ItemClass> tempItemList = GetCartList();
        return GetItemGroups(tempItemList , c => c.ItemCategory.ID + "|" + c.ItemCategory.Name + "|" + c.ItemCategory.IMPath);
    }

    private static ObservableCollection<Group<T>> GetItemGroups<T>(IEnumerable<T> itemList, Func<T, string> getKeyFunc)
    {
        IEnumerable<Group<T>> groupList = from item in itemList
                                          group item by getKeyFunc(item) into g
                                          orderby g.Key
                                          select new Group<T>(g.Key, g);

        //return groupList.ToList();
        ObservableCollection<Group<T>> t = new ObservableCollection<Group<T>>();
        foreach (Group<T> sublist in groupList)
        {
            t.Add(sublist);
        }

        return t;
    }
```

How I'm handling deletes:

```
        this.cartList.Remove(editingCartItem);

        ObservableCollection<Group<ItemClass>> t = (ObservableCollection<Group<ItemClass>>)LongListSelectorObj.ItemsSource;

        foreach (Group<ItemClass> sublist in t)
        {
            if(sublist.Contains(editingItem))
                sublist.Remove(editingItem);
            break;
        }
```

It's a little bloated as I made recent changes to try and make everything an ObservableCollection thinking it'd fix my issue at the time. It did help for other things, but I think it boils down to the lists simply being different.

I think I can change this to directly bind the ObservableCollection>, but then I believe I'd lose the easy adding/sorting, right?

Also, I assumed the issue might be because I'm trying to remove the item from two separate lists. However I've tried it with only one and I still have the same exception issue wich I assume is from the cast (ie. being able to delete everything up until the second to last, then last item).

Much appreciation for any incoming help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ViewModel implemented correctly, then removing an T object from an ObservableCollection does indeed remove it from the LLS's ItemsSource! When the collection is modified, the ObservableCollection will fire the CollectionChanged event, which it has because of inheriting from the INotifyCollectionChanged interface.

I would definitely read up on the MVVM strategies because it looks like something is wrong in your implementation.

As for your current solution,

You have several misspellings floating around. I would download ReSharper which pinpoints these very quickly for you. Stuff like:

- `<ITemClass>` // the capital T
- `private ObservableCollection<Model.Cartitem> cartList = new ObservableCollection<Model.allItems>();` // Model.Carditem versus Model.allItems?

If you think it's a casting issue, it's very wise to check your null statements everytime you try and access a class property. It's also good to use the `as` syntax [(link)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-s-the-difference-between-cast-syntax-and-using-the-code-as-code-operator.aspx), which helps with null checks.

```
DataType data = value as DataType; 
if (data != null) {
    string title = data.Title;
}
```

For this line,

```
this.cartList.Remove(editingCartItem);
```

Try turning it into this:

```
if (editingCardItem != null && this.cardList.Contains(editingCartItem)){
    this.cardList.Remove(editingCardItem);
}
```

Also, should your `sublist` be removing `editingItem` or `editingCardItem`? Keep these things in mind.

Otherwise, I would clean up your code, but I cannot see any other glaring issues without going deeper as your code is a bit over the place and it's difficult to parse through the syntax. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the notes, I did do some bad editing in my copy and paste to get it here (shortened all the names), but will still get Reshaper. And will try much of what you've suggested.

I hadn't been using a string MVVM pattern in this as I started long before I learned about it, and then was told for a simple app (say two pages) I didn't really need it, so I didn't try to change it. Should I?